# scraping basketball results and associate related competition to each match

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape basketball results from this webpage:
http://www.nowgoal.group/nba/Schedule.aspx?f=ft2&date=2020-07-29

I created the code using bs4 and requests:

```
url = http://www.nowgoal.group/nba/Schedule.aspx?f=ft2&date=2020-07-29

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
    r = session.get(url, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

The issue I face is how to add competition to each row I scrape
I want to create a table and each row is the match results (competition, home team, away team, score...)

Comment: is this all code ? You created `BeautifulSoup` but now you have to use `find`, `find_all` and other methods to get data from `soup`.

Comment: I checked - this page uses JavaScript to add elements - but requests/BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you may try to use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`, filter `XHR`) to find url used by JavaScript /AJAX (XHR) to get data from server. And then maybe you get even JSON data which you can easily convert to Python's data without scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Selenium

Try this (selenium):

```
import pandas as pd
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
res =[]
url = 'http://www.nowgoal.group/nba/Schedule.aspx?f=ft2&date=2020-07-29'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
page = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
span = soup.select_one('span#live')
tables = span.select('table')
for table in tables:
    if table.get('class'):
        competition = table.select_one('a b font').text
    else:
        for home, away in zip(table.select('tr.b1')[0::2], table.select('tr.b1')[1::2]):
            res.append([f"{competition}",
                        f"{home.select_one('td a').text}",
                        f"{away.select_one('td a').text}",
                        f"{home.select_one('td.red').text}",
                        f"{away.select_one('td.red').text}",
                        f"{home.select_one('td.odds1').text}",
                        f"{away.select_one('td.odds1').text}",
                        f"{home.select('td font')[0].text}/{home.select('td font')[1].text}",
                        f"{away.select('td font')[0].text}/{away.select('td font')[1].text}",
                        f"{home.select('td div a')[-1].get('href')}"])
df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['competition',
                                'home',
                                'away',
                                'home score',
                                'away score',
                                'home odds',
                                'away odds',
                                'home ht',
                                'away ht',
                                'odds'
                                ])

print(df.to_string())
df.to_csv('Res.csv')
```

prints:

```
                                 competition                              home                       away home score away score home odds away odds home ht away ht                                                  odds
0            National Basketball Association            Portland Trail Blazers      Oklahoma City Thunder        120        131      2.72      1.45   50/70   63/68  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387520.html
1            National Basketball Association                   Houston Rockets             Boston Celtics        137        112      1.49      2.58   77/60   60/52  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387521.html
2            National Basketball Association                Philadelphia 76ers           Dallas Mavericks        115        118      2.04      1.76   39/64   48/55  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387522.html
3    Women’s National Basketball Association                   Connecticut Sun         Washington Mystics         89         94      2.28      1.59   52/37   48/46  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/385886.html
4    Women’s National Basketball Association                       Chicago Sky         Los Angeles Sparks         96         78      2.72      1.43   40/56   36/42  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/385618.html
5    Women’s National Basketball Association                     Seattle Storm             Minnesota Lynx         90         66      1.21      4.19   41/49   35/31  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/385884.html
6                       Friendly Competition                  Labas Pasauli LT              Balduasenaras         85         78                       52/33   31/47  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387769.html
7                       Friendly Competition                        BC Vikings            Nemuno Banga KK         66         72                       29/37   30/42  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387771.html
8                       Friendly Competition                          NRG Kiev                    Hizhaki         51         76                       31/20   28/48  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387766.html
9                       Friendly Competition                           Finland                    Estonia         97         76      2.77      1.40   48/49   29/47  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387740.html
10                      Friendly Competition                           Synkarb              Sk nemenchine         82         79                       37/45   38/41  http://data.nowgoal.group/OddsCompBasket/387770.html
```

and so on....

And saves a `Res.csv` that looks like this:

[image]

---

### Requests

Try this (requests):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res = []

url = 'http://www.nowgoal.group/GetNbaWithTimeZone.aspx?date=2020-07-29&timezone=2&kind=0&t=1596143185000'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('h')

for item in items:
    values = item.text.split('^')
    res.append([f'{values[1]}', f'{values[8]}', f'{values[10]}', f'{values[11]}', f'{values[12]}'])
df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['competition', 'home', 'away', 'home score', 'away score'])

print(df.to_string())
df.to_csv('Res.csv')
```

prints:

```
   competition                              home                       away home score away score
0          NBA            Portland Trail Blazers      Oklahoma City Thunder        120        131
1          NBA                   Houston Rockets             Boston Celtics        137        112
2          NBA                Philadelphia 76ers           Dallas Mavericks        115        118
3         WNBA                   Connecticut Sun         Washington Mystics         89         94
4         WNBA                       Chicago Sky         Los Angeles Sparks         96         78
5         WNBA                     Seattle Storm             Minnesota Lynx         90         66
6           FC                  Labas Pasauli LT              Balduasenaras         85         78
7           FC                        BC Vikings            Nemuno Banga KK         66         72
8           FC                          NRG Kiev                    Hizhaki         51         76
```

And saves a Res.csv that looks like this:

[image: csv]

If you do not want the index column you can simply add `index=False` to `df.to_csv('Res.csv')` so it looks like this `df.to_csv('Res.csv', index=False)`

**Note selenium**: You need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`

The selenium version is slower but has no need to fetch and find the `XML` file with `devtools`

Comment: My best guess with no more info is that your connection to the site is a bit slow and you need to set `time.sleep(2)` to a higher value... Maybe `time.sleep(5)`  will fix it? @Ravanelli

Comment: yes, I did time sleep and worked, any possibility to add the other data like links (a title="Odds") and HT to the table ?

Comment: we can add links (a title="Odds")?

Comment: I am note sure if i misunderstood you? But https://i.imgur.com/uPE4tWn.png odds is in the data. @Ravanelli

Comment: no not img, the href of the a that have attribute title="Odds"

Comment: @Ravanelli changed my post again

Comment: @Ravanelli look at the selenium code now... Do i still misunderstand what you want?

Comment: Perfect... Sorry I did not understand you at first @Ravanelli

Answer (score 1):

This page uses `JavaScript` to load data but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

So you have two options.

**First:** you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. It can be better when page use complex JavaScript code to generate data - but this slower because it needs to run web browser which has to render page and run JavaScript.

**Second:** you can try to use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR`) to find URL used by `JavaScript`/`AJAX`(`XHR`) to get data from server and use this URL with `requests`. often you can get `JSON` data which can be converted to Python list/dictionary and then you don't need `BeautifulSoup`to scrape data. It is faster but sometimes page uses some JavaScript code which hard to replace with Python code.

---

I choose second method.

I found it reads data from

http://www.nowgoal.group/GetNbaWithTimeZone.aspx?date=2020-07-29&timezone=2&kind=0&t=1596143185000

but it gives XML data so it still needs `BeautifulSoup` (or `lxml`) to scrape data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://www.nowgoal.group/GetNbaWithTimeZone.aspx?date=2020-07-29&timezone=2&kind=0&t=1596143185000'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('h')

for item in all_items:
    values = item.text.split('^')
    #print(values)
    print(values[8], values[11])
    print(values[10], values[12])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
Portland Trail Blazers 120
Oklahoma City Thunder 131
---
Houston Rockets 137
Boston Celtics 112
---
Philadelphia 76ers 115
Dallas Mavericks 118
---
Connecticut Sun 89
Washington Mystics 94
---
Chicago Sky 96
Los Angeles Sparks 78
---
Seattle Storm 90
Minnesota Lynx 66
---
Labas Pasauli LT 85
Balduasenaras 78
---
BC Vikings 66
Nemuno Banga KK 72
---
NRG Kiev 51
Hizhaki 76
---
Finland 97
Estonia 76
---
Synkarb 82
Sk nemenchine 79
---
CS Sfaxien (w) 51
ES Cap Bon (w) 54
---
Police De La Circulation (w) 43
Etoile Sportive Sahel (w) 39
---
CA Bizertin 63
ES Goulette 71
---
JS Manazeh 77
AS Hammamet 53
---
Southern Huskies 84
Canterbury Rams 98
---
Taranaki Mountainairs 99
Franklin Bulls 90
---
Chaophraya Thunder 67
Thai General Equipment 102
---
Airforce Madgoat Basketball Club 60
HiTech Bangkok City 77
---
Bizoni 82
Leningrad 75
---
chameleon 104
Leningrad 80
---
Bizoni 71
Zubuyu 57
---
Drakony 89
chameleon 79
---
Dragoni 71
Zubuyu 87
---
```